# Dropdown menu being overshadowed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a template here but there seems to be some problem with the drop down menu.I have trouble figuring out the problem here.
[image]

there are two other links under link 1 in admission section. Here is the git ink to complete repo....

https://github.com/alpha0308/school-

Comment: Yes, please include the HTML and CSS.

Comment: _If so **please request** i will give the git link for the same_ why we request you while the requirement is yours?

Comment: @sagarV what i meant was is i am not sure if style sheet and html file are needed by you guys to solve the problem thats it

Comment: Yes. Without code, how are we supposed to solve it?

Comment: I suggest you to read the [ask] with [mcve] before asking questions.

Comment: Without code we can assume things and guide you wrong.From what I understand is that you can give z-index to the dropdown.Anyway,Please share the codes.

Comment: i have updated the question with the link

Comment: You should add the code here

Comment: Anyway, I made a PR. check whether it is fixed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code, and I see you have `"overflow: hidden"` on your container. This makes the dropdown div unable to show beneath the header's container.

Tested it and works for me with `"overflow: visible"`.

Comment: I see now that you rely on the "overflow: hidden" on another container in the page, so don't forget to assign it only to the header's container: `header .container {..}`